# Problem with nginx rate limiting not working when using white listing

Tags: nginx

I have nginx rate-limiting working when using the following

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:20m rate=50r/m;
```

I now want to apply it to certain IPs so i've changed it to

```
   geo $limit {
    default 1;
    1.2.3.4/32 0;
  }

   map $limit $mylimit {
     0 "";
     1 $binary_remote_addr;
   }

   limit_req_zone $my_limit zone=mylimit:20m rate=50r/m;
```

Following the example here https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

But the rate limit is ignored even when coming from a different IP than the one in the config

This is using nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

In the server block I have

```
limit_req zone=mylimit burst=15 nodelay;
```

which was working before